# How to disable dates between the saved events in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using a fullcalendar for creating schedules. What I am doing is, for each week, there must be only 3 schedules (processing date, payout date and credit date). If there are already schedules for that week, I need to prompt the user that schedules are already set. But if there's no schedule set, user can still post new schedule. I am already done with the logic of this scheduler, the only problem I have is how to disable dates between the set schedules for the week?

Example, I set 04-24-2018(processing date), 04-24-18(payout date) and 04-26-18(credit date)..

How can I disable the 04-22-18,04-23-18,04-25-18,04-27-18 and 04-28-18 on that week so that user cant create new schedules for that week?

[schedule image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J18bO.png)

JAVASCRIPT

```
select:
            function (start, end, jsEvent, view, resource) {
            IsDateHasEvent(start);
}

function IsDateHasEvent(date) {
    var allEvents = [];
    allEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    var event = $.grep(allEvents, function (v) {
        //alert(v.start);
        //return +v.start == +date;
        if (v.start <= date) {
            $("#eventIsAlreadySetModal").modal();
            //alert(v.start);
        }

    });
    return event.length > 0;
}
```

I can get all the dates with events whenever I try to alert the value of start date. But the dates between are still not disabled.

Can someone help me through this?
Thank you so much.

Full Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var events = [];
    var selectedEvent = null;
    FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();


    // ******************************************
    // GET ALL SCHEDULES AND DISPLAY IN CALENDAR
    // ******************************************
    function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSchedule")',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    var eColor = "";
                    if (v.status == 'Completed')
                    {
                        eColor = '#3498DB';
                    }
                    if (v.status == 'Active') {
                        eColor = '#2CB05B';
                    }
                    if (v.status == 'Pending') {
                        eColor: '#DE6209';
                    }

                    events.push({
                        eventID: v.scheduleId,
                        title: v.processedDescription,
                        start: moment(v.processedDatetimeStart),
                        status: v.status,
                        color: eColor
                    });

                    events.push({
                        eventID: v.scheduleId,
                        title: v.payoutDescription,
                        start: moment(v.payoutDatetimeStart),
                        status: v.status,
                        color: eColor
                    });

                    events.push({
                        eventID: v.scheduleId,
                        title: v.creditDescription,
                        start: moment(v.creditDatetimeStart),
                        status: v.status,
                        color: eColor,
                        end: moment(v.creditDatetimeStart)
                    });


                })


                GenerateCalendar(events);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        })
    }


// ******************************************
    // GENERATE THE CALENDAR VIEW AND SCHEDULES
    // ******************************************
    function GenerateCalendar(events) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            contentHeight: 500,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay, listWeek'
            },
            navLinks: true,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            eventColor: '#2CB05B',

            droppable: false,
            timeFormat: 'h(:mm)A',
            timeZone: 'local',

            events: events,

            // **************************************
            // display the saved schedule in calendar
            // **************************************
            eventClick:
            function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {                    
                $("#statusLabel").text(calEvent.status);
                $("#schedId").val(calEvent.eventID);
                $("#schedDesc").html(calEvent.title);
                $("#txtDateStart_Edit").val(calEvent.start.format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm A"));
                $('#modalEditSchedule').modal();

                if ($("#statusLabel").html() == "Completed")
                {
                    $("#btnEditSched").hide();
                }

                if ($("#statusLabel").html() == "Active") {
                    $("#btnEditSched").hide();
                }

            },

 // *************************************************
            // select dates in calendar for posting new schedule
            // *************************************************
            selectable: true,
            selectOverlap: true,
            select:
            function (start, end, jsEvent, view, resource) {

                IsDateHasEvent(start);
            },

 // *********************************************
            // disable past navigation button for past dates
            // *********************************************
            viewRender: function (currentView) {
                var minDate = moment();
                // Past dates
                if (minDate >= currentView.start) {    
                    $(".fc-prev-button").prop('disabled', true);
                    $(".fc-prev-button").addClass('fc-state-disabled');
                }
                else {
                    $(".fc-prev-button").removeClass('fc-state-disabled');
                    $(".fc-prev-button").prop('disabled', false);
                }
            },

            // ******************************
            // disable past dates in calendar
            // ******************************
            validRange: function (dateNow) {
                return {
                    start: dateNow.subtract(1, 'days')
                };
            }

            , dayClick: function (date) {
                var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
                for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                    //if (moment(date).isSame(moment(events[i].start))) {
                    if (moment(events[i].start) <= moment(date)) {
                        alert('with events');
                        break;
                    }
                    else //if (i == events.length - 1) 
                    {
                        alert('none');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // **********************************
    // show modal for adding new schedule
    // **********************************
    function openAddEditForm() {
        $('#modalAddSchedule').modal();
    }



});

function IsDateHasEvent(date) {
    var allEvents = [];
    allEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    var event = $.grep(allEvents, function (v) {
        //alert(v.start);
        //return +v.start == +date;
        if (v.start <= date) {
            $("#eventIsAlreadySetModal").modal();
            //alert(v.start);
        }

    });
    return event.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you not provide a working example of what you currently have? Only the relevant parts.

Comment: Hi @NewToJS, I already edited my question and added a screenshot of my calendar view. Thank you so much for response. Hoping that you can help me out.

Comment: The calendar is working for adding new schedule. The only problem that almost took me days is how can I disable the dates that are not having schedules for each week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- check if there's at least 3 schedules on the same week;
- if is there, then disable the other dates of that week.

Right? I'll try to solve the first part of your problem with [javascript Date class](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). I don't know about FullCalendar, so if anyone can solve that part I would be glad, hehe.

We must check when a week starts and when it ends. Just with that we'll get ready to do some crazy stuff.

```
function printDate(year, month, day) {
    month = (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month.toString();
    day = (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day.toString();
    return year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}
function weekStart(dateString) {
    var dateObject = new Date(dateString);
    var dayOfWeek = dateObject.getDay();
    if(dayOfWeek > 0) {
        dateObject.setDate(day - dayOfWeek);
    }
    return printDate(dateObject.getFullYear(), dateObject.getMonth()+1, dateObject.getDate());
}

function weekEnd(dateString) {
    var dateObject = new Date(dateString);
    var dayOfWeek = dateObject.getDay();
    if(dayOfWeek < 6) {
        dateObject.setDate(day + (6-dayOfWeek));
    }
    return printDate(dateObject.getFullYear(), dateObject.getMonth()+1, dateObject.getDate());
}
function weekRange(dateString) {
    return [weekStart(dateString), weekEnd(dateString)];
}
```

Nice, now we can get a "week range" from a date. But from that, can we get all dates of that week? Sure.

```
function getDatesFromWeek(wStart) {
    var dates = [],
        date = new Date(wStart),
        count = 0;
    while(count <= 6) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + count);
        dates.push(printDate(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate());
        count++;
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Perfect. So now we should count for each range. Assuming you're receiving your info on a variable called `schedules` and each schedule have an index called `date`:

```
var weeks = {}, lockedDates = [];
for(var x in schedules) {
    var week = weekRange(schedules[x].date);
    var weekID = week.join('-');
    if(weeks[weekID] == undefined) {
        weeks[weekID] = 1;
    } else {
        weeks[weekID]++;
    }
    if(weeks[weekID] == 3) {
        lockedDates = lockedDates.concat(getDatesFromWeek(week[0]));
    }
}
```

Then you have all those dates to disable listed on `lockedDates` variable in format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Do you know how to do the rest?

## EDIT

Let's change the last part I made to this:

```
function Locker() {
     this.dates = [];
     this.weeks = {};
}
Locker.prototype.add = function(dateString) {
    var wStart = weekStart(dateString);
    if(this.weeks[wStart] == undefined) {
        this.weeks[wStart] = 1;
    } else {
        this.weeks[wStart]++;
    }
    if(this.weeks[wStart] == 3) {
        this.lock(getDatesFromWeek(wStart));
    }
}
Locker.prototype.lock = function(dates) {
    this.lockedDates = this.lockedDates.concat(dates);
    // do something
}
var calendarLocker = new Locker();
// everytime an user add a date, call calendarLocker.add(date);
// so when it reaches the limit, the locker will call calendarLocker.lock
```

Comment: Hi @Kiko Garcia, thank you for your response. Can you tell me how can I do this whenever the user clicks on the date in calendar?

Comment: @da26 please look my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks you for this. It helped me a lot and I already resolved my problem. I've just added some lines of codes and it works. Thank you again.